# Setting Delegate Outside UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates, iad

I am trying to isolate iAd initialization code from the main UIViewController as much as possible to achieve an easy integration for my apps in the future. I created AdManager (NSObject) class to deal with iAd setup and initialization. However, I do not know how to set up delegates for objects outside UIViewController which implements these delegate classes. For example:

```
@interface AppViewController : UIViewController<ADBannerViewDelegate>
```

and my AdManager would have something like this:

```
+(void)initAdBannersInView:(UIView*)view andViewController:(UIViewController*)vc{
  ADBannerView *iAdBannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -bannerSize.height, bannerSize.width, bannerSize.height)];
  iAdBannerView.delegate = vc;  
  [view addSubview:iAdBannerView];
```

Error (warning) message is: Assigning to 'id' from incompatible type 'UIViewController'

I may not be very good with this particular situation about delegates, so pardon my possible misunderstanding but is it possible to achive what I need in a similar way? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining the `vc` argument as `UIViewController *`.  That means you can pass any old view controller in there, not necessarily one that conforms to the `ADBannerViewDelegate` protocol.  You should define the `vc` argument so that you can only pass view controllers that conform to that protocol in:

```
+(void)initAdBannersInView:(UIView*)view andViewController:(UIViewController<ADBannerViewDelegate>*)vc{
```